# CIS for a Javascript project

Tags: javascript, jenkins, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I was wondering what is the best solution to implement a CIS for a Javascript project. I've googled it, and I'm not sure what will be the optimal solution.

I've taken a look to Jenkins and Travis. The first one requires an installation and I'm not sure if it is the best for a JS project. The second one has a great integration with Github (which is a plus for my case) but is quite expensive as well

I hope to get an advice from you masters of CIServering

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to think about what you need, perhaps you'll find useful this post: http://blog.clinkerhq.com/hosted-continuous-integration-comparative

There is a list of things to think before selecting a CI service and then a comparison between some of the current options.